# Why property getter for ui:repeat called during restore view phase?

Tags: jsf-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Figuring out why JSF getters are called when I don't expect them to be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078477/figuring-out-why-jsf-getters-are-called-when-i-dont-expect-them-to-be-called)

Here is a simple test case that shows a list of customers one page at a time:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="#{controller.nextPage()}" value="Next" />

    <ui:repeat value="#{controller.customerList}" var="c">
        #{c.name}<br/>
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>

public String nextPage() {
    //...
    return null;
}
```

During a postback, getCustomerList() gets called during restore view, apply request values and render response phase. It only makes sense when the method is called during the render response phase. The other two calls seem completely wasteful and serves no purpose other than to put undue load on the database. I can not cache the list after it is loaded in restore view phase, since, a different list for the next page has to be loaded in render response phase. I do not wish to store the managed bean in session because that will drain memory.

Can you please explain why JSF must call the property getter method for the ui:repeat in restore view and apply request values phase when no other property getter of the managed bean is called at that time? Thanks.

Comment: another related question: [<ui:repeat> in JSF 2.0 breaks methods execution order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358430/uirepeat-in-jsf-2-0-breaks-methods-execution-order)

Comment: I have seen those questions before posting. They didn't give me a clear idea. Also, here I tried to simplify the test case quite a bit.